# error "\" in tabular model/Analysis service

Tags: ssas, plsqldeveloper

I upload the code to the tabular model section:

```
 begin
      p param.Setparam('db', to_date('01.08.2023','dd.mm.yyyy'));
    end; 
    /
    select /*+ Parallel(32) */ * from storages.v_test_load rb;
```

`I get the following error: Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLEDB or     ODBC error: ORA-06550: line 1, column 74: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" . '.`
How can it be solved? shielding doesn't help

the query should return a table that is returned to pl\sql developer